# How to install puffin browser in Linux?

Tags: linux, puffin-browser

I tried to install puffin browser in Linux using wine.It asks for .NET framework v4.6. I separately installed it.Then it crashes with CLR Runtime Error.

Answer (score -1):

On rasperry pi it is called puffin internet terminal.

https://github.com/ZhymabekRoman/Puffin-Browser-on-Linux

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Once the link dies, the answer will become useless.